# Does $\tan(1/z)$ has a Laurent series convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis

Well, I have no idea: Does $\tan(1/z)$ have a Laurent series convergent on $0<|z|<R$?

Comment: It is preferable to use `\tan`, `\sin`, `\log`, `\cos`, `\exp` etc in math mode instead of `tan`, `sin`, `log`, `cos`, `exp` etc

Comment: ok, thank you, i did not know that.

Comment: Where does it have poles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the answer is no. The function $\tan(1/z)$ has poles at $z=\frac{1}{\pi/2+n\pi}$, which means that it is not analytic on the annulas you mentioned for any $R$.